# What are SignInResult() and SignOutResult() used for in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've spotted `SignInResult()` and `SignOutResult()` as possible return types in my web application.

They're part of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` namespace.

See below example

[image]

What are they for?

Do they play any useful role in login/logout scenarios on a website?

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=SignInResult+sample

Comment: Have you done any kind of search https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.signinresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @Nkosi Yes I found that. I was hoping for a basic example. The documentation doesn't provide this.

Comment: @StuartAitken . Please refer to http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/03/29/asp-net-core-action-results-explained/ . It has detailed explanation about that in `Security related action results` section .

Comment: @NanYu That's excellent, thank you